# React Navigation navigate works like goBack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native project I want users to navigate to the Login page. And, at the login page, user can fill the inputs to log in. Then, if log in process is successful, user should navigate back to the Homepage.

I am doing all the navigations with this.props.navigation.navigate function. But at the login page, the navigate function doesn't work as I expected. It works like the goBack function. By that I can't update homepage's state.

What should i do for navigate function to work as the way it works always ?

Comment: Could you post your User journey? Like: `HomePage > Login > Homepage (success) | LoginPage (error)` and perhaps some code?

Comment: Homepage (navigate) > Login   => success **** Login (i want navigate, but it works like goBack) > Homepage => error ****** Codes are only navigate(...) functions. Nothing else :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

#### Use `Modal`. (Recommend)

Wrap your `homeStack` and `AuthStack` using `createStackNavigation` with a `Modal` option. or use `createSwitchNavigation`.

```js
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    Auth: {
      screen: AuthStack,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
  }
);
```

OR

#### Using ‘push’ or ‘replace’ instead of ‘navigate’ can be other options.

### Why?

It works as `goBack` even though you use `navigate` in stackNavigation if screen is stacked already as your process home->login->home. Thus, using `modal` can be a one of simple and cool way.

Modal: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html

Comment: dude, thanks so much. 'push' is what i have been looking for. you made my day!!

Comment: @burakkesepara My pleasure :) Happy coding!